# Setting Material UI select / Drop Down width

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a material-ui grid setup.  Each `<Grid>` has `<Paper>` to show where the grid is, exactly. 
 Inside each `<Paper>`, I have a `<DropDown>` (Which is a custom wrapper on the Material-UI `Select`.  I would like these DropDown components to fill the parent component (`<Paper>`).

My code and styling for my `DropDown` component is based, almost verbatim, on the Material UI select code example.  The code for each `DropDown` component is:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    formControl: {
        margin: theme.spacing(1),
        minWidth: 120,
    },
    selectEmpty: {
        marginTop: theme.spacing(2),
    },
}));

function DropDown(props) {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const inputLabel = React.useRef(null);
    const [labelWidth, setLabelWidth] = React.useState(0);
    React.useEffect(() => {
        setLabelWidth(inputLabel.current.offsetWidth); 
    }, []);


    const handleValueChange = (e) => { 
        if (props.alternateChangeHandler) {
            props.alternateChangeHandler(props.currentEventID, props.id, e.target.value);
        } else {
            props.SEQuestionValueChange(props.currentEventID, props.id, e.target.value);
        }
    };

    return <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
        {(props.label != null)
            ? <InputLabel htmlFor={props.id}>{props.label}</InputLabel>
            : null
        }
        <NativeSelect
            value={props.value}
            onChange={handleValueChange}
            inputProps={{
                name: props.label,
                id: props.id,
            }}
        >
            {props.includeBlank ? <option key="nada" value="" /> : null}
            {Object.keys(props.options).map((optionLabel, index) =>
                <option key={optionLabel} value={props.options[optionLabel]}>{optionLabel}</option>
            )}
        </NativeSelect>
        {/* <FormHelperText>Some important helper text</FormHelperText> */}
    </FormControl>
```

I fail to get the width I'm hoping for... as you can see here:

[image]

As you can see, the DropDowns are not filling the `<Paper>`... AND are not appropriately sized based on the label size.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by changing the form control tag to this:

... but that pushes the select a little wider than the `<Paper>` due to margins and what not... so I shrunk it back by adding
        `paddingRight: '20px'` to the `formControl` style.

Looking deeper, the fullWidth={true} simply adds width='100%' to the style anyway... so that also does it.